# How can I execute a JavaScript function at random when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, function, random, onload

I want to execute a JavaScript function `showDonate()` at random when the page is loaded. Meaning that this function **is executed sometimes** and **not executed sometimes** when the page has been loaded. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could update `showDonate()` to be:

```
function showDonate() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) return;

  //existing code
}
```

And then add:

```
<body onload="showDonate()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is what you need:

```
if(Math.random()>0.5)
    {
        showDonate();
    }
```